getent passwd only shows ldap user from OU People
I've connected my Solaris 11 Server with my OpenLDAP Server. The connection works and with "ldaplist" I can see the ldap users that should be in the search base.
Looks like that:
dn: cn=user_1,dc=IT,dc=my-company,dc=com
dn: cn=user_2,dc=IT,dc=my-company,dc=com
dn: cn=user_3,dc=IT,dc=my-company,dc=com
dn: ou=People,dc=IT,dc=my-company,dc=com

Now the command "getent passwd" returns only users in the ou People, but only ou People, I can not change the name, if I do nothing will be returned.
My problem is that I've never configured that ldapclient or getent passwd should use the ou People.
Also my ldap_client_file file, generated by ldapclient says that I don't use ou People. It looks like this:
NS_LDAP_SERVERS= my-companies-ldap-server.com:636
NS_LDAP_SEARCH_BASEDN= dc=IT,dc=my-company,dc=com
NS_LDAP_AUTH= tls:simple
NS_LDAP_CACHETTL= 0
NS_LDAP_CREDENTIAL_LEVEL= proxy

Would be great if someone has an Idea.
Thanks!
